# How to exclude logging.exception from logfile, but include it in stdout without defining custom logging level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have custom logger with default levels. I want to show `logging.exception` "level" in logfile, but exclude it from stdout (I want to leave short error messages in stdout). It's important that I don't want to declare custom level, because I want to leave some customisation space for user (switch off my logging a.e.).

So this is the code:

```
import logging
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dataclasses import fields
from API.global_constants.dataclasses import LoggerTemplate
from API.global_constants.vars import LOGGER_NAME


def set_logger(**kwargs):
    logger_template = LoggerTemplate()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key in [field.name for field in fields(logger_template)]:
            setattr(logger_template, key, value)

    if not isinstance(logger_template.logger, logging.Logger):
        logger_template.logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
    else:  # means logger has been overriden by user
        return logger_template.logger

    logger = logger_template.logger

    if not logger_template.enable_logger:
        logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL + 1)
    else:
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        std_formatter = Formatter()
        std_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        std_handler.setLevel(logger_template.log_std_level)
        std_handler.setFormatter(std_formatter)
        logger.addHandler(std_handler)

        if not logger_template.enable_logfile:
            logger.info(f'Logging started without file.')
        else:
            file_formatter = logging.Formatter(f"[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s/%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s]  %(message)s")
            Path.mkdir(Path(logger_template.logfile_path), parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            log_file_path = Path(logger_template.logfile_path) / Path(str(logger_template.logfile_name))
            file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_path)
            file_handler.setLevel(logger_template.logfile_level)
            file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
            logger.addHandler(file_handler)
            logger.info(f'Logging started in the [{log_file_path}].')

    return logger


class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):

        color = {
            logging.CRITICAL: 31,
            logging.ERROR: 31,
            logging.FATAL: 31,
            logging.WARNING: 33,
            logging.DEBUG: 36,
            logging.INFO: 32
        }.get(record.levelno, 0)
        self._style._fmt = f"\033[37m[%(asctime)s]\033[0m \033[{color}m%(levelname)-8s\033[0m %(message)s"
        return super().format(record)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger1 = set_logger(logfile_name='some_user_defined_name')
    logger1.debug('test message')
    logger1.info('test message')
    logger1.warning('test message')
    logger1.error('test message')
    logger1.critical('test message')
    logger1.exception('test message')
```

And the dataclass (as a logging config template) from the `set_logger` function:

```
import logging
import sys
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path


@dataclass
class LoggerTemplate:
    enable_logger: bool = True
    enable_logfile: bool = False
    logger: logging.Logger = None
    logfile_path: str = Path(f'logfiles_[{os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])}]')
    logfile_name: str = Path(f"{datetime.now().strftime('__%d.%m.%Y__%H.%M.%S')}__.log")
    logfile_level: int = logging.INFO
    log_std_level: int = logging.DEBUG
```

So, how can i print logging messages, including `logging.exception` messages in logfile, but exclude `logging.exception` messages in stdout, replacing it with `logging.error` short variants ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a simple example which sticks close to the core `logging` APIs. See this script:

```
import logging
import sys

class NoExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return ''

def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('so_77873508.log', 'w')
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    FMT = '%(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    f1 = logging.Formatter(FMT)
    f2 = NoExceptionFormatter(FMT)
    ch.setFormatter(f2)
    fh.setFormatter(f1)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f'Failed: {e}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

When run, it prints no exception to the console but does to the file:

```
$ python so_77873508.py
ERROR    Failed: division by zero
$ more so_77873508.log 
ERROR    Failed: division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/redacted/so_77873508.py", line 22, in main
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much!!! :D. I also wanted to use logging API, but I chose the wrong path - decided to use Filters. Btw, thank you again!